# Typescript: How to reference the name of interface's property?

Tags: typescript, interface

I would like to check on runtime if object has the specific property from the specific interface. I could just hardcode the name of this property in the place of runtime checking, but I would like to use some kind of a reference. Just so when I'll decide to change this property name in the future, I won't need to change it in the place of this runtime check.

I thought about:

```
const groupsMethodName = 'groups';

interface Groups {
    [groupsMethodName](): string[]|null;
}
```

That way I could reference `groupsPropertyName` later in the code. It works for the type checking, but this method has one ugly drawback: IntelliJ IDEA and probably every other IDE will not recognize that this interface has property "groups". So methods from the `Group` interface implemented in the class implementing this interface, won't be marked as methods of this interface in the editor.

Another idea that came to my mind would be to do something like this:

```
class Groups {
    groups(): string[]|null {
        return null;
    }
}

interface Groups extends Groups {}
```

That way I could reference interface's method name later with `Groups.prototype.groups.name` .

This solves the previous issue, now IDE knows that `groups` is a method of this interface, and I can easily check for its existence later, without hardcoding it as a string (IDE's refactoring will recognize this reference).

But it's so ugly.

Is there a better way of referencing interface's method name in a way that would be understandable by popular IDEs?

**Added:**

I just figured out one other solution, which seams quite bearable.

We can create an "InterfaceMetadata" type and object with information about our interface. By using generics we can have not a lot of additional code, and type guarded sync between object and interface it describes.

```
export interface GroupsInterface {
    groups(): string[]|null;
}

type InterfaceMetadata<Interface> = {
    [Property in keyof Interface]: Property;
}

const groupsMetadata: InterfaceMetadata<GroupsInterface> = {
    groups: "groups",
}
```

We can now get interface metadata from the `groupsMetadata` object. I kind of like it, but could we do better?

Comment: I don't understand about the IDE issue; if you look at [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mLRbKw) you can see that the IDE definitely knows that `Groups` has a method named `groups`. Of course I had to edit `groupsPropertyName` to `groupsMethodName`... that typo makes me think this code isn't a [mre].  Could you double check that the issue you're seeing is truly happening and, if so, edit the code example to be something others could drop into a standalone IDE like the TS Playground to demonstrate it for themselves?  Right now I'm just confused.

Comment: @jcalz It was just a mistake in the example. The issue is with IDEs, not TS itself. When I create a class implementing this interface, no `(i)` icon will show up next to a `groups` method implemented by this class in IDE's editor. So there will be no indication that this is implementation of the interface. IDE cannot recognize this relationship, because interface is created dynamically, and IDE provides mostly static analysis.

Comment: I suppose you should tag this as being about your IntelliJ IDE since I cannot reproduce with the TS Playground IDE nor with VSCode.  The TS Playground IDE definitely knows that `Groups` has a method named `"groups"` and it displays it as `groups  (method) Groups[groupsMethodName](): string[] | null` via IntelliSense.